# Each fruit is a combination of two elements

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Hello Puzzling community!

Here's a simple [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) question I created recently:

> **1)** Apple = **50 X**
> **2)** Banana = **33 G**
> **3)** Cherry = **77 Y**
> **4)** Dragon Fruit = **137 G**

> **5)** Elderberry = **`?#1`**
> **6)** Forest Strawberry = **`?#2`**
> **7)** Grape = **`?#3`**

Hope you enjoy this one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number/letters are

> The sum of the letters in A1Z26, and then the letter is the number in the alphabet of the number mod26

An example for ‘Apple’:

> Apple = 1 + 16 + 16 + 12 + 5 = **50**
> 50 mod 26 = 24
> 24th letter is **X**
> Apple = **50 X**

So for the unknown fruits

> Elderberry = **112 H**
> Forest Strawberry = **232 X**
> Grape = **47 U**

Comment: you're too fast ^^

Comment: 7 seconds xD I shouldn't have double checked, lol

Comment: @LukasRotter wow that was incredibly close!! Honestly you should leave your answer up because you still deserve credit for getting it at almost the same time :)

Comment: Well, I knew it was easy, but you took less than 10 minutes to get the correct answer (are you human?). It's nice, your reputation speaks for you, congratulations! :)

Comment: @xKobalt I actually got the letter before I got the numbers and realised the numbers after lol. And I guess I’m not human, I’m gerbil :P